# unable to access keyCode/key event on input event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to console log the event key on input bound input event on the input, below is what I've tried

```
<div id="app">
    <input @input="onInput" @keyup="onKeyUp" type="text">
</div>
```

vue script

```
new Vue({
    el : '#app',
    methods : {
        onInput(event){
            console.log(event.key); // returns undefined ?
            console.log(event.keyCode); // returns undefined ?
        }
        onKeyUp(event){
            console.log(event.key); // returns the key name
            console.log(event.keyCode); // returns the keycode ?
        }
    }
});
```

but it gives me `undefined` but on keyup, it gives me the key name and keycode just what I expected, only on the `onInput` method gives me `undefined`. Any help, ideas?

Comment: Try defining your method as -> onInput: function(event) {....}

Comment: @Riddhi still gives me undefined

Comment: @Riddhi on keyup method '@keyup/v-on:keyup' returns the correct output any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are neither `key` or `keyCode` properties on an `input` event. If you want to listen to specific keyboard events, use the dedicated listeners.

`input` is designed to get all events modifying form elements values under one umbrella, to provide means of detecting subtle changes, like the ones which are performed while a slider is dragged without being released or while the value changes repeatedly when you're holding down the up/down arrow on a `type="number"`  input.

Your best match is the `event.data` property (or you can get particular properties of `event.target`). But really, if you want to detect the press of a particular `key`, use [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown).

Current official recommendation for [*Input*](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-input) event.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this is where you can find answer, sounds to me like it should be it
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/get-value-from-input/15854

I hope it helps.